# Implementing pacman game issue when moving it up and down

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simple pacman game, and I just got started.

Currently my constructor looks like this:

```
static String[][] board;
static int pacmanBornHeight;
static int pacmanBornWidth;

public PacmanKata(int height, int width) {

    board = new String[height][width];
    pacmanBornHeight = (int) Math.floor(height / 2);
    pacmanBornWidth = (int) Math.floor(width / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "*";
        }
    }
    board[pacmanBornHeight][pacmanBornWidth] = "V";
}
```

This constructor set up the board and the pacman will be located at the middle, I used "V" as the symbol.

I try to create two methods currenlty, move up and down.

Here is the setup:

I first called the tickUp method:

```
public void tickUp(int steps) {
    int counter = 1;
    int timer = 0;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < steps; loop++) {
        board[pacmanBornHeight - counter][pacmanBornWidth] = "V";
        for (int innerTimer = 0; innerTimer < counter; innerTimer++) {
            board[pacmanBornHeight - innerTimer][pacmanBornWidth] = " ";
        }
        counter++;
        timer++;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
} //end going UP
```

And I print out this to console(I initialized a 10 by 10 board):

[image]

Pacman moved up three steps, as expected, and eat three dots. I slightly modified and created a move down method:

```
public void tickDown(int steps) {
    int counter = 1;
    int timer = 0;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < steps; loop++) {
        board[pacmanBornHeight + counter][pacmanBornWidth] = "V";
        for (int innerTimer = 0; innerTimer < counter; innerTimer++) {
            board[pacmanBornHeight + innerTimer][pacmanBornWidth] = " ";
        }
        counter++;
        timer++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}//end tickDown
```

Now I called tickDown and asked it to move down 3 steps, but I got this result:

[image]

The trouble I am having is, I do not know how to locate the Pacman last location. The move down method simply created a new Pacman and moved down 3 steps, that is not what I want. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can also use a 1d array instead of a 2d array; you'd have a single `int pacmanPosition`, +1 to move right, +10 to move "down".

Comment: @Brian I will need to implement movement from left to right after I fixed my current problem, that is why I choose 2d array.

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate a 1d board :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `tickUp` and `tickDown` methods to save the new position of your Pacman:

```
public void tickDown(int steps) {
    int counter = 1;
    int timer = 0;
    for (int loop = 0; loop < steps; loop++) {
        for (int innerTimer = 0; innerTimer < counter; innerTimer++) {
            board[pacmanBornHeight + innerTimer][pacmanBornWidth] = " ";
        }
        pacmanBornHeight += counter;
        //Allow for wraparounds:
        if (pacmanBornHeight > board.length) {
            pacmanBornHeight = 0;
        }
        board[pacmanBornHeight][pacmanBornWidth] = "V";
        timer++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}//end tickDown
```

I moved the loop to write spaces in the board to the beginning of the outer loop; that way you get the spaces based on the starting position of Pacman.  Once you've written the spaces to the array, you update Pacman's position and write it in the array.

Edit:

Here's an example showing how you'd use a one-dimensional array as your board:

```
public class PacmanKata {
    static String[] board;
    static int pacmanPosition;
    static int boardHeight;
    static int boardWidth;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PacmanKata kata = new PacmanKata(10,10);
        kata.tickUp(7);
        kata.tickRight(9);
    }

    public PacmanKata(int height, int width) {
        boardHeight = height;
        boardWidth = width;
        board = new String[height*width];
        int offset = (width + 1) % 2;
        pacmanPosition = (int) Math.floor((height + offset)*width/2);

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = "*";
        }
        board[pacmanPosition] = "V";
    }

    private void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(board[i]);
            if ((i+1) % boardWidth == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
    }

    public void tickUp(int steps) {
        int counter = -1 * boardHeight;
        for (int loop = 0; loop < steps; loop++) {
            //Current position = ' '
            board[pacmanPosition] = " ";
            //Pacman's position changes:
            pacmanPosition += counter;
            //Allow for wraparounds:
            if (pacmanPosition < 0) {
                pacmanPosition += board.length;
            }
            //Update the board with Pacman's new position:
            board[pacmanPosition] = "V";
        }

        printBoard();
    }//end tickUp

    public void tickRight(int steps) {
        int counter = 1;
        for (int loop = 0; loop < steps; loop++) {
            //Current position = ' '
            board[pacmanPosition] = " ";
            //Pacman's position changes:
            pacmanPosition += counter;
            if (pacmanPosition % boardWidth == 0) {
                pacmanPosition -= boardWidth;
            }
            //Update the board with Pacman's new position:
            board[pacmanPosition] = "V";
        }

        printBoard();
    }//end tickUp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `pacmanBornWidth` and `pacmanBornHeight` fields, you should have a field with pacman current position (all fields shouldn't be static):

```
String[][] board;
java.awt.Point pacmenPos;

public PacmanKata(int height, int width) {

    board = new String[height][width];
    pacmanPos = new Point((int) width/2, (int) height/2);

    for (int i = 0; i < boardHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardWidth; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "*";
        }
    }
    board[pacmanPos.x][pacmanPos.y] = "V";
}
```

Now replace all occurrences of `pacmanBornWidth` and `pacmanBornHeight` with `pacmanPos.x` and `pacmanPos.y`.

And in your `tickUp` and `tickDown` methods, just update pacman position:

```
public void tickUp(int steps) {
    ...
    pacmanPos.translate(0, steps);
    ...
}

public void tickDown(int steps) {
    ...
    pacmanPos.translate(0, -steps);
    ...
}
```

---

This will also work the same if you add `tickLeft` and `tickRight` methods:

```
public void tickLeft(int steps) {
    ...
    pacmanPos.translate(-steps, 0);
    ...
}

public void tickRight(int steps) {
    ...
    pacmanPos.translate(steps, 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using a single `pacmanPos` variable is a good idea, but your solution glosses over updating the board with spaces where Pacman has eaten the pills.